# JFrame visibility

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, visible

I tried to make a JFrame with netbeans IDE and all the code has no error, when I try to run the application the Frame is not visible. what is the problem?

Comment: Please share your code. Else we cant help...

Comment: Please show the code anyway. Please also include the code that opens the JFrame (the "main" method, most likely)

Comment: I got it guys, I forgot to make this line:

    setVisible(true);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you forgot to write this code:

```
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: yea man , thanks for reminding me , as iam new to java netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do

```
setVisible(true);
```

Make sure that you made a constructor like:

```
public YourFrame(){
setVisible(true);
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score -2):

After i tried all the solutions and nothing worked, i copied individual objects like buttons and text boxes into a new form and running the form after each addition. It finally worked.